# How can we find the determinant of $2A^TA$ while only knowing the determinant of A and the order of the matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, transpose

If $A$ is a square matrix of order 3 and $det(A)=5$, then how much is $det(2A^TA)$?

Assuming the product of a matrix and its transpose is nothing special how do we solve this question?

This was a previous year test question so I don't think it's a long process, there must be some rule I am missing.

Comment: If you don’t know the appropriate rules, but assume the question is well-posed (that is, that the answer just depends on the information provided, not on other properties of $A$), then you can just pick $A$ and calculate.  For instance, let $A$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $5,1,1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: if $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $a$ is a scalar, then $\det(aB)=a^n\det B$.

Hint 2: $\det(A^T)=\det A$

Do you need a third hint? I hope not.